# Filter out groups in pandas based on values in groups

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Currently i have a dataframe looking something like this

| Session Id | Time | Event | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10:00 | Btn click | foo |
| 1 | 11:00 | Identification | bar |
| 2 | ... | Btn click | foo |
| 2 | ... | Btn click | foo |
| 3 | .. | Identification | bar |

I want to group my data by Session Id and process the groups further, but only if they possess an Identification Event.

Currently my solution looks like this:

```
for session in df.groupby('Session ID'):
    session_df: pd.DataFrame = session[1]
    if 'Identification' in session_df['Event'].values:
        process(session_df)
```

I tried to use filter on the groupby but got something wrong:

```
for session in df.groupby('Session ID').filter(lambda s: 'Identification' in s['Event'].values):
    process(session[1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

make codition by `groupby` + `transform`

```
cond = df['Event'].eq('Identification').groupby(df['Session Id']).transform(sum).gt(0)
out = df[cond]
```

out :

```
    Session Id  Time    Event           Data
0   1          10:00    Btn click       foo
1   1          11:00    Identification  bar
4   3          ..       Identification  bar
```

if you want `groupby` + `filter`, use following code:

```
df.groupby('Session Id').filter(lambda x: x['Event'].eq('Identification').sum() > 0)
```

same result

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Session Id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3], 
         'Time': ['10:00', '11:00', '...', '...', '..'], 
         'Event': ['Btn click', 'Identification', 'Btn click', 'Btn click', 'Identification'], 
         'Data': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and `any` for test at least one value match per groups:

```
out = df[df['Event'].eq('Identification').groupby(df['Session Id']).transform('any')]
```

Or use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
out = df[df['Session Id'].isin(df.loc[df['Event'].eq('Identification'), 'Session Id'])]
```

Or use [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html):

```
s = df['Event'].eq('Identification').groupby(df['Session Id']).any()
out = df[df['Session Id'].isin(s[s].index)]
print (out)
   Session Id   Time           Event Data
0           1  10:00       Btn click  foo
1           1  11:00  Identification  bar
4           3     ..  Identification  bar
```